# magento get all configurable options with products id

Tags: product, configurable-product

i want to show color swatches from products id ( product object)

i tried below code

```
$product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
```

gives output like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [label] => Filter Name
            [use_default] => 0
            [position] => 0
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_super_attribute_id] => 2
                            [value_index] => 220
                            [label] => Topaz
                            [default_label] => DEF
                            [store_label] => DEF
                            [is_percent] => 0
                            [pricing_value] => 210.0000
                            [use_default_value] => 1
                            [value_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_super_attribute_id] => 2
                            [value_index] => 217
                            [label] => Quartz
                            [default_label] => ABC
                            [store_label] => ABC
                            [is_percent] => 0
                            [pricing_value] => 195.0000
                            [use_default_value] => 1
                            [value_id] => 2
                        )
                )

            [attribute_id] => 1171
            [attribute_code] => filter1name
            [frontend_label] => Filter Name
            [store_label] => Filter Name
        )

)
```

i want product is also with each value array option , how can i get that

Comment: which form of value array option do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);

$attributeOptions = array();

foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
    $configurable= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product);
    $simpleCollection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

    foreach($simpleCollection as $simple){
        $simple_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simple->getId())->addAttributeToSelect($productAttribute['attribute_code']);
        $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label'][$simple->getId()]=$simple_product->getData($productAttribute['attribute_code']."_value");
    }
}
```

**Print** `$attributeOptions` **array**